# Isomorphic graphs derived from $K_{10,10}$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, graph-isomorphism

> How many subgraphs of $K_{10,10}$ exist that are isomorphic to the graph $G$ on the picture?

I can think of $P(10,10)$ but I don't think that all of these cases are isomorphic with $G$

[image: graph G]

Comment: where did you post G?

Comment: @justaguy It's on the link. Can't embed, not enough reputation.

Comment: Your graph $G$ has odd cycles.  A bipartite graph such as $K_{10,10}$ cannot have any odd cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider each vertex as unique then: Pick any 3 vertices from the 10 and they will form a triangle. Then pick another 3 from the remaining 7 and they form a triangle then another 3 from the remaining 4 and they form a triangle then the remaining one is connected to all three triangles so you can form the graph G. Thus the answer is ${10}\choose{3}$${7}\choose{3}$${4}\choose{3}$$=16800$